# Common pattern of scan() where I don't ultimately care about the state

Tags: scala, state, fold

I find myself constantly doing things like the following:

```
val adjustedActions = actions.scanLeft((1.0, null: CorpAction)){
  case ((runningSplitAdj, _), action) => action match {
    case Dividend(date, amount) => 
      (runningSplitAdj, Dividend(date, amount * runningSplitAdj))
    case s @ Split(date, sharesForOne) => 
      ((runningSplitAdj * sharesForOne), s)
  } 
}
.drop(1).map(_._2)
```

Where I need to accumulate the `runningSplitAdj`, in this case, in order to correct the dividends in the actions list.  Here, I use `scan` to maintain the state that I need in order to correct the actions, but in the end, I only need the actions.  Hence, I need to use null for the initial action in the state, but in the end, drop that item and map away all the states.

**Is there a more elegant way of structuring these?**  In the context of RxScala Observables, I actually made a new operator to do this (after some help from the RxJava mailing list):

```
implicit class ScanMappingObs[X](val obs: Observable[X]) extends AnyVal {
 def scanMap[S,Y](f: (X,S) => (Y,S), s0: S): Observable[Y] = {
   val y0: Y = null.asInstanceOf[Y]
    // drop(1) because scan also emits initial state
    obs.scan((y0, s0)){case ((y, s), x) => f(x, s)}.drop(1).map(_._1)
  }
}
```

However, now I find myself doing it to Lists and Vectors too, so I wonder if there is something more general I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The combinator you're describing (or at least something very similar) is often called `mapAccum`. Take the following simplified use of `scanLeft`:

```
val xs = (1 to 10).toList

val result1 = xs.scanLeft((1, 0.0)) {
  case ((acc, _), i) => (acc + i, i.toDouble / acc)
}.tail.map(_._2)
```

This is equivalent to the following (which uses [Scalaz's implementation of `mapAccumLeft`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.syntax.std.ListOps)):

```
xs.mapAccumLeft[Double, Int](1, {
  case (acc, i) => (acc + i, i.toDouble / acc)
})._2
```

`mapAccumLeft` returns a pair of the final state and a sequence of the results at each step, but it doesn't require you to specify a spurious initial result (that will just be ignored and then dropped), and you don't have to map over the entire collection to get rid of the state—you just take the second member of the pair.

Unfortunately `mapAccumLeft` isn't available in the standard library, but if you're looking for a name or for ideas about implementation, this is a place to start.